# Check if array elements are filled in java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a simple reservation system with 10 elements (seats). I want to check if elements from 1 to 5 has been set. If Yes, then set the elements from 6 to 10 (Vice-Versa).

An element should not be assigned a value more than once. My code so far.

```
    boolean[] seats = new boolean[10];

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Choose FirstClass(1) / Economy(2): ");
    int flightClass = input.nextInt();

    for (int j = 0; j < seats.length; j++) {
        System.out.println("\nEnter Seat Number: ");
        int enterSeat = input.nextInt();
        if (flightClass == 1) {
            if (enterSeat >= 0 && enterSeat <= 5) {
                System.out.println("You're in the First Class.");

                seats[enterSeat] = true;
                System.out.printf("You're Seat Number is %d\n", enterSeat);

            }

        } else if (flightClass == 2) {
            if (enterSeat >= 6 && enterSeat <= 10) {
                System.out.println("You're in the Economy.");

                seats[enterSeat] = true;
                System.out.printf("You're Seat Number is %d\n", enterSeat);
            }

        }
```

My Question: How do I check if elements from 1 to 5 has been set, and if they have, set the elements from 6 to 10, and vice versa?

For example:

Enter seat no. to book:
1

Enter seat no. to book:
2

Enter seat no. to book:
3

Enter seat no. to book:
4

Enter seat no. to book:
5

All the first class seats(1-5) has been set. Now the remaining seats are from 6 - 10.

Enter seat no. to book:
6 so on...

Comment: You code will give you an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, since you are eventually trying to access `seats[10]`. Arrays are 0-index based...

Comment: How to check if elements from 1 to 5 has been set. If Yes, then set the elements from 6 to 10 (Vice-Versa). @Baz: Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Please be clearer about what you would like the code to do. And please replace "You're" with "Your". "You're" only ever means "You are" so pedantic people like me will get irate when they see such a grammatical error.

Comment: Seems you are buying a ticket fist class and when you want to take your seat it becomes unavailable and you go to economy.

Comment: Yes, When I buy a seat in the first class section. That seat cannot be booked the second time. It should display an error. But, how i do I implement that?

Comment: You have to switch the class then. So money refund.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays in Java<sup>1</sup> are indexed from zero, not from one. Therefore, your code that checks `>=1` and `<=10` should be changed to `>=0` and `<=9`, or use<sup>2</sup>

```
seats[enterSeat-1]
```

instead of

```
seats[enterSeat]
```

To find the next available element from among the elements of a sub-array, you can use this loop:

```
int firstFree = -1;
for (int j = 0 ; j != 5 ; i++) {
    if (!seat[j]) {
        firstFreeSeat = j;
        break;
    }
}
if (firstFreeSeat == -1) {
    System.out.printl("Sorry!");
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> As well as C, C++, C#, Objective C, and many other languages

<sup>2</sup> This is something you may want to do if you expect the user to enter numbers one through ten rather than zero through nine - a more natural choice for seat numbering.

Comment: If I booked seats[2] once and the second time if I book seats[2] again. How can check I display an error message?

Comment: @RonyJohn You can do this: if (seats[2]) { /*your code*/ }` This will check if `seats[2]` is set to `true` or `false`.

Comment: Do I have to do the same thing for each element? Is there an easier way?

Comment: @RonyJohn You do not have to do it one by one - you can use a loop. Take a look at the edit. For the second half of the array you would need to use different indexes, but the logic can stay the same.